# How to set a password on github or jenkins before push to master branche for a user

Tags: jenkins, github

Jenkins is configured in a way that every time you run the command git push origin master, an automatic deployment will be set to the production environment.
every user on git can push to master
I want to lnow how to limit the access to the production environment for example how to configure git or jenkins to demand a password before proceeding to deployment to production environment?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot require an additional password to push to a specific branch on GitHub.  Git has no way to provide anything but a single username and password for HTTPS or normal SSH authentication (which on GitHub means just a public key) for SSH.

If you want to restrict people from deploying automatically, there are some options.  First, you can use GitHub's protected branches feature to restrict direct pushes to `master` and require people to use pull requests to merge there.  You can then impose review requirements (using CODEOWNERS or otherwise), require CI jobs to pass, and implement other checks.

The other choice is to use some sort of external deployment mechanism instead of using a direct push to master, and then you can use that service to impose whatever restrictions you like.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For Jenkins is there a way to require a password before running a job ?

Comment: I don't know whether Jenkins provides that functionality, but my guess is that since it's a CI system and is designed to automate things, it isn't designed to perform custom access control before doing the automation.